# C# reading ALL of a process' memory

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management, process

Ello!

Trying to read the memory of a running process, and it does actually work, somewhat. Issue here is I found out that my end address,
`IntPtr endOffset = IntPtr.Add(startOffset, getProcess.MainModule.ModuleMemorySize);`, only gives me the amount of memory that is required to load the module.

Thus giving me a lot of unread memory of the process that is allocated later on.
The code I have written is not really interesting at all, but this is how I get my startaddress and endaddress, where clearly the endaddress is not including all of the later allocated memory.

```
        Process getProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("processname")[0];
        IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, getProcess.Id);
        IntPtr startOffset = getProcess.MainModule.BaseAddress;
        IntPtr endOffset = IntPtr.Add(startOffset, getProcess.MainModule.ModuleMemorySize);
```

My "solution" atm is just to add a high decimal number to the end address, which naturally makes it read a lot of other memory that is not even of the process I want and of course slows the reading down a lot.

So what I need your guys help with is how do I ensure that all of the process' memory is read? I know its most likely sorted out in chunks in the memory but I am not sure how I can pinpoint later start addresses and end addresses at where ever that is located in memory.

Thank you!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Interesting, will look at this and see if I can figure something out, Thank you!

Comment: I made VirtualQueryEx work, however I am not sure what to do with the output I get. "65536-131071 : 65536 bytes result=28" is the outputs I am getting. It seems like its not jumping any memory addresses but just increases in how many bytes it reads while looping through memory. How is the output supposed to be understood?